# Table Reference In Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, reference, ref

I have two models 1 : UserSchema & 2 :todo

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    todo: { desc }  
}

const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema {
    id: id,
    desc : String
}
```

So my query is I want to get the todo of user based on id from on "todo" collection based on user id.

The my final result will be :

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("63a73aded28fd96ab66a9f30"),
    name: 'world',
    email: 'world@gmail.com',
    todo: [],
    __v: 0,
}
```

How to get the todo data using mongodb?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB, or document databases in general, are different from relational database (like MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.) as MongoDB doesn't support relations natively as relational databases do. Yet, mongoose (the ODM for MongoDB in node.js) and its models has a way to represent relations using the model reference. So, your models are going to be:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema{ name: String, email: String, todo: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Todo' } }
const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema{ desc : String }
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);
```

And to get the user and `populate` their `todo`, you can do the following query in mongoose

```
const user = await User.findById(id).populate('todo')
```

I also suggest you go through this page on mongoose documentation on populate function https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

To do the query directly on MongoDB without mongoose, you can do the following query using aggregates.

```
db.users.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "_id": 1
    }
},
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "todos",
        "localField": "todo",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "todo"
    }
}])
```

Comment: yes. But how to store the id the reference to the user table. Like when user login, the data of user with todo description should be displayed based on id. So The above query will work in this case?

Comment: should I pass "_id" : id which getting from the session?